# PhoneGap Custom Language setup

Tags: android, css, cordova, phonegap-build

I have tried many examples and non of them are work.Here is what i want to do. I have a phonegap eclipse project.here is the project structure

[image]

I want to add custom language for my project. here is my MainActivity.java

```
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

 }
}
```

Here is my index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-   scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width;" />
  <title>Directory Reader</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
  <script src="jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
  @font-face {
   font-family: MyCustomFont;
   src: url("NotoSansSinhala-Regular.eot") /* EOT file for IE */
  }
   @font-face {
   font-family: MyCustomFont;
   src: url("NotoSansSinhala-Regular.ttf") /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers */
  }

  body {
  font-family: MyCustomFont, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: medium;
  color: black
  }
  </style>


 </head>
 <body>

 <p> test goda </p>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Still font that i want to display is not showing on the mobile device.its shows english characters "test goda". any idea how to slove this?

Comment: any idea to solve this.

Comment: did u truied to run  index.html on broswer?

Comment: no.. but how do i know the location of the index.html when the app is installed on the device..i have tried by giving index.html location on the browser.but browser is also displaying English characters.Not the font that i want to display.

Comment: yes , first you need to try on broswer , may be there is some issues with refrance of ut fonts files....plz reviwew ur code again and test first on broswer.

Comment: fonts are on the root forlder. i couldn't find where the error is.anyway thank you for your help

Comment: inside assets/www/html files+fonts.. folder strure can be found on the image.. fonts names are  NotoSansSinhala-Regular.otf and NotoSansSinhala-Regular.ttf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would basically need to root the device to install Sinhala text on Android 4.4 , but it works on Android 5.0+

You would basically need below steps :

1. Copy the font files to /system/fonts
2. Download the fallback_fonts.xml file from /etc
3. Open the fallback_fonts.xml file and modify it by adding your font
   names .Copy the file back to the /etc directory.
4. Change the permissions of your fallback_fonts.xml file AND the font
   files to 644 or -rw-r–r–

Plese see read instructions with screenhots [here](http://blog.malinthe.com/2014/04/how-to-get-perfect-sinhala-text-on-android-4-4-kitkat/)